# Parallel tests in Android with cucumber, appium and testNG in java

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng, appium-android

I have 5 real devices in which I want to execute 20 tests, for example: 4 tests in each device in parallel, that is, in device 1 test 1 is executed, when the test ends, test 2 follows, in device 2 test 5 , at the end of test 5, follows 6... I can only run 1 test on each device in parallel, when I run more than 1, the test fails. Is there a way to specify that the current test is expected to finish before the next one starts? I am using Cucumber, Appium, testNG

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For example how are running your tests? How did you configure your test runner to run in parallel? How are tests distributed between workers?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje I run the tests from the main cucumber class which extends from AbstractTestNGCucumberTests, to run in parallel just add '@Override
@DataProvider(parallel=true)
public object[][] scenarios(){
return super.scenarios();
}', in each test class I specify which device to use with the UDID.
If parallel = false, test 2 runs only when test 1 finishes, but if parallel = true, test 2 doesn't wait for test 1 to finish and blocks the script.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to set `dataproviderthreadcount` somehow.

And that depends on how you run TestNG.

- Via the CLI:  https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng
- Via Maven: https://maven.apache.org/surefire-archives/surefire-2.21.0/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html